# К приложению на Fast Api при запуске из контейнера Docker не удаётся подключиться

Tags: docker, веб-сервер, dockerfile, порт

Я создал контейнер с приложением на Fast Api. Вот мой Dockerfile для билда контейнера:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY r.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r r.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "127.0.0.1", "--port", "8000"]
```

.При попытки обращении к сайту по 127.0.0.1:8000 у меня ничего не выходило. Можете пожалуйста подсказать, что я не правильно делал?
Запускал я контейнер на Linux Mint такой командой:

```
$sudo docker run -p 8000 forum
```

Comment: `127.0.0.1` -> `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Требуется заменить 127.0.0.1 на 0.0.0.0, в первом случае FastAPI будет прослушивать только внутри контейнера, во втором появится доступ с хостовой машины.